# Screw axis in P21c space group

Tags: group-theory

I am having some trouble with understanding glide axis. The following is a question asking to reconstruct the full unit cell: 
[image]

And the following is the answer to the question:

[image]

I have highlighted an element which I want to focus on. I understand the rotation of 180 degrees and translation of 1/2 of a unit cell. However, I don't understand why the element undergoes a change from 1/2 + to - . My understanding of 1/2 + is that it is located 1/2 above the left element following a glide plane (c) transformation. But I don't understand why it would be transformed into a "-" after the axis screw. I also don't understand what 1/4 near the screw axis means, I'm guessing it could be that it is an axis at c = 1/4, but the transition that the highlighted element undergoes still doesn't quite make sense if that is the case.

Please provide any guidance with this question, I've been struggling to understand what is going on for a long time.

Many thanks

Comment: Well, the 1/4 near the screw axis means exactly what you're guessing. Also, it changes + to -, because, er, well, that's what all horizontal axes do. What were you expecting of a 180 degrees rotation? Just a shift along X and a reflection in Y, with no change in Z? That would be a plane.